# Using "act on" like an American

Tags: phrasal-verbs

I would like learn more about the phrasal verb "act on" in English. I found this while looking for examples:

> (act on/upon something) to do something because you have been given information, advice, or orders

Some examples I thought of:

- I was acting on crazy because you don't give me my cash and I let you
- I don't know what is it going but my mom is acting on my bff

Does this sound like what an American would say, or how should I use "act on"?

Comment: If you say things like "a american people" then you will not sound like an American.

Comment: i said that because i want to improve my english and speak like them

Comment: "Act" is a verb, "on" is a preposition, and what follows "on" is the remainder of the prepositional phrase.  I don't see how it's helpful to specify "act on" as a phrasal verb in the contexts you're considering.

Answer (score 2):

Both of your examples are wrong.  The definition says "because you have been given information".  So for example:

> The police acted on the tip they received.

> The manager refused to let me into the store.  He said he was acting on the government order that everyone must wear a mask.

Comment: okay i understood you but i did not understood that example

Comment: The police acted (probably arrested someone) _because_ they had been given information about a crime. The manager refused to let someone in _because_  of the orders from the government.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you’re confusing “act on” and the performative sense of “act,” as in, to act in a play.

The performative sense can take an adjective as a direct object to characterize someone’s behavior, as in your first example: act crazy.

The act in “act on” means to *take action* or to “do something,” as your definition puts it, and the on indicates *on what basis* (e.g., “because you have been given information”). The phrase isn’t used to characterize the subject’s behavior as having a particular tone. It’s used to indicate why he took action.